# Check if command in screen is running

Tags: gnu-screen

How can I check if command running in screen is still running or it output with exception ?? So I can report it to user.

Im trying to execute command which is inserting data to mysql but from time to time Im getting

```
[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Comment: Re-attach to the session and check? Are you trying to find the output of a command running in screen via a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`screen` can output logs with the `-L` option. Within an already existing `screen` session you can `Ctrl-a H` to turn it on. From there, you could conceivably tail the `screen` logs and parse it for various conditions that you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks simple but great anwser.